How to change locally beamer frametitle using pagestye?
I am trying to understand how works \thispagestyle and \ps@navigation in beamer documents.
I simplified the answer from this previous questions, and I just added \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=red}.
And I am quite puzzled by the fact that the background is correctly changed on the frame using [optionA] but not the frametitle.
A similar question has been asked, but the answer is completely avoiding the problem, using tricks to change the content of the frametitle not its style or color.
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}


\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{myBG}{
   \includegraphics{example-image-a}
}
\defbeamertemplate*{test}{name}{
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[myBG]
    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=red} % I would really prefer having it here but it was no effect.
}

\makeatletter
   \define@key{beamerframe}{optionA}[true]{
      \thispagestyle{navigation@optionA}
      % \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=red} % here it has effect even after the frame that has the `optionA`.
   }
   \def\ps@navigation@optionA{
      \usebeamertemplate{test} % I also tried with *, **, ***
      % \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=red} % Not my favorite spot, but it was no effect neither.
      \@nameuse{ps@navigation}
   }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

   \begin{frame}{normal frame}
      a normal frame.
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}[optionA]{special frame}
      Here, I should have a background and a red frametitle.
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}{normal frame}
      another normal frame.
   \end{frame}

\end{document}

So, in a beamer document, how can I change locally the frametitle style using \thispagestyle (and if possible a simple template definition) ?

you can not change the frametitle in the page style, as the page style is set later.
And generally beamer's option are not really well suited for such a setup. As beamer collects its body the \end{frame} is normally never executed and that means that the grouping behaviour is different to typical environments. I would simply define a general environment that does your setup and that you can put around the whole frame:
\documentclass{beamer}


\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{myBG}{%
   \includegraphics{example-image-a}}

\newenvironment{useframeoptionA}{%
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[myBG]%
  \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=red}}{}

\begin{document}

   \begin{frame}{normal frame}
      a normal frame.
   \end{frame}


\begin{useframeoptionA}

   \begin{frame}{special frame}
      Here, I should have a background and a red frametitle.
   \end{frame}
   
    \begin{frame}{another special frame}
      Here, I should have a background and a red frametitle.
   \end{frame}
   
\end{useframeoptionA}

   \begin{frame}{normal frame}
      another normal frame.
   \end{frame}

\end{document}


I agree with your environment solution, that I knew to work. However, I was looking for a solution using beamer option even though I understand that this is well suited for such situation. But it is annoying to setup environment every time for 1 slide.

\begin{xxx} ... \end{xxx} is not much more typing than [optionA], and as you can use arguments (including keyval arguments) in the environment it is much more flexible.  So why do you want spent hours to tweak an unwilling option system not meant for this purpose?
